# How do you filter dataframe based off value of column in another dataframe and whether the string of a column in that dataframe is a substring?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that look like this:

```
#df1
id   |  minyear
x       01/01/2019
y       01/02/2019
z       01/03/2019
#df2
id2   |   date 
xx         01/01/2018   
xx         01/02/2019      
xx         01/01/2020     
yy         01/02/2018
yy         01/03/2019
yy         01/04/2020
zz         01/01/2019
zz         01/05/2020
```

What I want to do is if the *id* column is a substring of *id2* then I would like to to only keep the values in *df2* that are greater than its minyear value. So the final dataframe should look like this:

```
id2   |   date 
xx         01/02/2019      
xx         01/01/2020     
yy         01/03/2019
yy         01/04/2020
zz         01/05/2020
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
# convert the columns to datetime (skip if they are converted already):
df1.minyear = pd.to_datetime(df1.minyear)
df2.date = pd.to_datetime(df2.date)

x = df1.merge(df2, how="cross")
x["tmp"] = x.apply(lambda r: r["id"] in r["id2"], axis=1)
x = x[x.tmp & x.date.ge(x.minyear)][["id2", "date"]]
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   id2       date
1   xx 2019-01-02
2   xx 2020-01-01
12  yy 2019-01-03
13  yy 2020-01-04
23  zz 2020-01-05
```